# How do I configure Emacs to use 'ispell' on Mac OS X?

Tags: osx, emacs

I'm using `brew` as my package manager for both Emacs and ispell. I have both installed. Doing a quick google, I was unable to figure out how to tell Emacs where ispell is and to load the appropriate dictionaries.

Right now when I do a `M-x ispell-check-version`, Emacs saucily replies: `Searching for program: No such file or directory`.

**How do I configure `Emacs` to use `ispell`?**

Answer (score 17):

The variable you're looking for is `ispell-program-name`.
Stuff this somewhere in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq ispell-program-name "/path/to/ispell")
```

Or use `M-x set-variable`, etc.

References:

- From the sources to `ispell.el`

  ```
  (defcustom ispell-program-name
    (or (locate-file "aspell"   exec-path exec-suffixes 'file-executable-p)
        (locate-file "ispell"   exec-path exec-suffixes 'file-executable-p)
        (locate-file "hunspell" exec-path exec-suffixes 'file-executable-p)
        "ispell")
    "Program invoked by \\[ispell-word] and \\[ispell-region] commands."
    :type 'string
    :group 'ispell)
  ```
- See also: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractiveSpell

Whenever you can't find an Emacs function, remember `C-h f` (or a variable: `C-h v`). Entering `ispell` at the `Describe function` prompt tells you that `ispell is an interactive compiled Lisp function in 'ispell.el'.`, and from there you can usually find what you're looking for.

Comment: If you use set-variable to set ispell-program-name make sure you put double quotes around the value.  In my case it was "/opt/local/bin/aspell"

Answer (score 14):

What helped me solve this without editing my `.emacs` with absolute paths (which I was reluctant to do, as I share the file between different OSs) was installing ispell via brew

```
brew install ispell --with-lang-en
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17128203/544059) (and my comment).

Answer (score 1):

This is an environment variable issue. The `exec-path-from-shell` package fixed this problem for me.

After evaluating `(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)`, ispell worked.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this must be a resolved issue by now, but still wanted to add that I have been successfully using ispell in Mac OS X. Installing ispell in homebrew and then adding the correct path in .emacs (/usr/local/bin) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use brew only for the ispell install and have installed emacs [from this type of dmg](http://emacsformacosx.com/), and you run emacs from an icon in the dock, you'll want to logout and login again, since OS X caches items in your path and won't see ispell immediately. If this information isn't news to you, then you can probably work around this issue anyway.